# shell: awk to int variable

Tags: awk

I have a speedtest-cli skript and try to awk the result. I want to get the downloadspeed as integer, so I can compair with other results in an If, then.. condition.

part of my skript:

```
#!/bin/sh


speedtest-cli | awk '/Download:/ {print $2} ' > /root/tmp1
read speed1 < /root/tmp1
speedtest-cli | awk '/Download:/ {print $2} ' > /root/tmp2;

read speed2 < /root/tmp2
if [ $speed1 -gt $speed2 ];then
echo "test";fi
```

The problem is, that my awk result (75.27) isnt saved as integer! When it comes to if, I get an error:
    sh: 75.27: bad number

I also would perfer to define the variable direct from the awk result, but that doesnt work!

```
speedtest-cli | var=$(awk '/Download:/ {print $2} ' > /root/tmp1)
```

How can I "awk" the speedtest-cli result, to get an variable that can be compaired in an if...then conditin?

please help,
thx greetings Igor

Comment: Does using `print int($2)` solve your problem?

Comment: Yes! Int($2) solved my problem. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

if you want to compare floating point numbers you can do within `awk` or with `bc -l`

for example

```
speed1=$(speedtest-cli | awk '/Download:/{print $2}')
...
speed2=$(speedtest-cli | awk '/Download:/{print $2}')

if (( $(echo "$speed1 > $speed2" | bc -l) )); then ...
```

another alternative is if you want to compare them as integers but don't want to lose digits due to rounding, multiply them with a large value and convert to int.

```
speed1000=$(speedtest-cli | awk '/Download:/{print int($2*1000)}')
...
```

now `bash` can handle integer comparisons...